# How can you turn $(x^2+1)$ into $(ax+b)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

It seems like it should easy, but it isn't so much. I am trying to find the simplest expression such that, when starting with the expression $$x^2+1$$, that one can find the simplest constants such that $x^2+1=(ax+b)^2$ or preferably $(x+b)^2$. How would one do this?
I suppose another way to ask it would be if $$f(x)=x^2+1,$$

and if $$f(g(x))=(ax+b)^2,$$ what is $g(x)$?

Comment: Why do you think you can do that?

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of algebraic complex expression like a=1/sqrt(2) and b=-sqrt(i). We need a repeated root, so b has to be negative to force the express to equal 0 at some point (if treating it like a function), but as for a...Well, there must be some kind of solution, but I am not sure how to determine the exact solution.

Comment: You say "there must be some kind of solution", but this is false. Just because an equation can be written, it doesn't follow that there is a solution. For example, there is no solution to the equation $x=x+1$.

Comment: A simpler proof than the approaches below, to the more general question at the end, is to note that $g(x)^2+1=(ax+b)^2$ with $a\ne0$ implies $$g(-b/a)^2+1=0$$ which is impossible since, whatever the real-valued function is, $$g(-b/a)^2\geqslant0$$ (For complex-valued functions $g$, a supplementary argument is needed.)

Comment: @JohnBentin There is a functional manipulation such that it is true, absolutely, but it has not been explicitly defined in terms of known functions, it requires niche manipulations. But you're right it's not true in the conventional sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two polynomials are considered equal if they have matching coefficients.

So $1x^2 + 0x + 1 = a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2$ if and only if

\begin{align}
   a^2 &= 1 \\
   2ab &= 0 \\
   b^2 &= 1
\end{align}

This implies that $|a| = |b| = 1$. Hence $2ab = \pm 2 \ne 0$. So there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible then the equality
$$x^2+1=(ax+b)^2$$
should be true for all real values of $x$.

Thus, $x^2+1=a^2x^2+2abx+b^2$, which gives $a^2=1$ for $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Indeed, we have
$$1+\frac{1}{x^2}=a^2+\frac{2ab}{x}+\frac{b^2}{x^2}$$
is true for all $x\neq0$.

Hence, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(a^2+\frac{2ab}{x}+\frac{b^2}{x^2}\right)$$ or
$$1=a^2.$$

Also, $b^2=1$ for $x=0$ and

$2ab=0$ for $((ax+b)^2)'_{x=0}=(x^2+1)'_{x=0}$.

Id est, we got $a^2=1$, $b^2=1$ and $2ab=0$, which is impossible.

I think the following way is shorter.

If $x^2+1=(ax+b)^2$ then it's says that this equality must be true for all real $x$.

Let $x=0$.

Thus, $b^2=1$ and we obtain:
$$x^2+1=a^2x^2+2abx+1$$ or
$$x((a^2-1)x+2ab)=0$$
should be true for all real $x$.

Thus, $(a^2-1)x+2ab=0$ should be true for all real $x$ (because a polynomial is a continuous function).

Now, for $x=0$ we obtain $2ab=0$ and since $b\neq0$ we obtain $a=0$.

Thus, after our assumption that $x^2+1=(ax+b)^2$ we got
$$x^2+1=1.$$
I think it's not so true for all real $x$.

Comment: You've only shown one possible outcome given certain assumptions. $x = (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 1} + a b)/(1 - a^2)$ is the general solution with unknown paramaters, so just make it so that a^2=/=1. The trick is to find a and b.

Comment: I also see no reason to assume it "should" be impossible for all values, since obviously we can't do much with a division by 0. If I plot x/x, well, 1 is a function that extends to all real numbers, and even though x/x algebraically reduces to 1, it is still acceptable that it is undefined at x=0. Similarly, it is the algebraic manipulation that shows a limitation in mathematics for defining a solution at a very particular point.

Comment: @DaneJoe I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: Why are you assuming a^2=1? That's the one value where you get a division by 0, of course it won't work for a=1. The statement is true with the condition that a=/=1. You should note this does not need to be limited to real numbers.

Comment: @DaneJoe I did not assumed it, I proved it. See please my post .

Comment: I am not seeing that you proved it as far as I can tell, your equation simplifies to $0=x^2(a^2-1)+2abx+b^2-1$ which has the solution $x = (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 1} + a b)/(1 - a^2)$ and then for some reason you choose $a$ to be equal to 1. Why are you taking a limit to infinity too?

Comment: @DaneJoe I added something.

Comment: I don't know if you're interpreting the question as it is written. If it's an impossible equation it should reduce to a direct contradiction, you shouldn't be taking limits to infinity or reciprocating x. Why are you assuming it should be true for all values of x in the first place if a division by 0 is shown possible in its solution? Why did you suddenly chose to do f(1/x) with seemingly no explanation?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383187/) out before engaging too seriously.

Comment: @dxiv "Page Not Found" What's the summary of it? Do you have any insight on this mathematical proof?

Comment: @DaneJoe this answer shows we cannot find $a,b$ such that $x^2+1=(ax+b)^2$ for all real $x$. If this is not what you are asking, could you clarify in your question? FWIW the part after "another way to ask it" doesn't clarify anything for me since it seems to be a very different question from the first part.

Comment: @stewbasic Can you cite a theorem that proves the statement? limit x->+oo 2/x^2= limit x->+oo 3/e^x but that doesn't mean 2=3 or x=e^x for all x or no x. Why should it mean anything just because the limits to infinity are the same? I see no explanation for that, we're not talking about limits to infinity, we're talking about values before infinity on the sub-finite number line.

Comment: @DaneJoe I don't understand your comment, but it's easy to prove without limits if you prefer. Substitute $x=-1,0,1$ to get $2=(b-a)^2$, $1=b^2$, $2=(b+a)^2$. Subtract first and third to get $ab=0$. But $b^2=1$ implies $b\neq0$, so $a=0$. Now $2=(b-a)^2=b^2=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @stewbasic But why are you assuming that $a$ and $b$ equal these random discrete values when the answer could easily be a complicated complex radical? I'm fine if a and b aren't real if that's what the issue is. I will say that intuitively what you're saying on its way to making some kind of sense, but I do not see that it is actually proven. The way I see it, if a and b are real, well, there's no "real" numbers such that (ax+b)^2 will be forced to cross the x axis given the constraint that it is equal to x^2+1.

Comment: @DaneJoe As in the comment above, my only assumption was that $x^2+1=(ax+b)^2$ for all $x$. The statements about $a,b$ were derived from that assumption. It may help to consider a simpler but analogous problem. Do you believe we can find an $a$ such that $2x=x+a$ for all $x$?

Comment: @stewbasic At this point I neither believe nor disbelieve any statements thus far. What I know is that no "real" numbers, a and b, exist to make the statement true based on the complex analysis interpretation that the angle between the two solutions will never be 0 (a.k.a there is no real a and b that will make the function cross the x axis), but as I said, I do not see how this rules out the possibility of complex solutions as well given the limits only go to positive infinity along the real number line anyway. I think there are multiple views, but the ones presented lack context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63903/discussion-between-stewbasic-and-danejoe).

Answer (score 0):

*The sum of the two roots of $p(x) = cx^2+d$ always vanish.* Since if $r_1$ is a root, then so is $r_2 = -r_1$.

Suppose we can write $p(x) = (ax+b)(ax+b)$. Then we have a repeated root $r_1 = r_2$. But the sum $r_1 + r_1 = 0$ implies $r_1 = 0$. But $p(0) = d = b^2 = 0$, implies that $p(x) = cx^2$.